# Bug in Sublime-Text 3 ? Ctrl+z and Ctrl+s

Tags: sublimetext3

My problem is that by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, the whole file is tabulated, and if I give it again that tab is removed, it also happens to me with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> ...

In the keys bindings, I have

```
{"keys": ["ctrl + z"], "command": "undo"},

{"keys": ["ctrl + s"], "command": "save"},
```

I do not get it...

And in Edit I get "Undo Emacs Tabstop to Spaces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>" ..

If someone can help me ..

regards

Comment: What does "is tabulated" mean? I would guess you have a package installed that's doing something weird.

Comment: Indented, sorry..Now I'm at work, but I remember I have installed amm Emmet, TypeScript...

Comment: Solved, I had the "Emacs Tabstops" package installed